# cypher union group by sum

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to boost edges for a  user depending of some rules base on graph traversal. Basically in mysql I would do that :

```
select id, sum(weight) as total
from
(
     select id, 10 as weight
     from user
     inner join userRel1 ON user.id = userRel1.userId
     where userRel1.attr1 in (1, 2)
  union
     select id, 5 as weight
     from user
     inner join userRel2 ON user.id = userRel2.userId
     inner join userRel3 ON user.id = userRel3.userId
     where userRel2.attr2 = 'a' and userRel3.attr2 = 'z'
  union
     ...
)
group by id 
order by total desc
```

Also, I have already writed this query with some help in gremlin 3 but I would like to compare performance with cypher. But I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345598/how-to-aggregate-result-of-union-in-cypher) that group by on union are not possible yet, it mean that cypher is less powerful than gremlin ? Would I have to set weight as properties on edges to achieve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*While it is true that post-`UNION` processing is [still an open feature request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725), you do not need to use `UNION` to perform your use case.*

This query should do the equivalent of your SQL (ignoring the incomplete part):

```
WITH [] AS res

OPTIONAL MATCH (user1:User), (userRel1:UserRel1) 
WHERE user1.id = userRel1.userId AND userRel1.attr1 IN [1, 2] 
WITH res, (CASE WHEN userRel1 IS NOT NULL THEN COLLECT({id: user1.id, weight: 10}) ELSE [] END) AS data 
WITH res + data AS res

OPTIONAL MATCH (user2:User), (userRel2:UserRel2)
WHERE user2.id = userRel2.userId AND userRel2.attr2 = 'a'
OPTIONAL MATCH (userRel3:UserRel3)
WHERE user2.id = userRel3.userId AND userRel3.attr2 = 'z' 
WITH res, (CASE WHEN userRel3 IS NOT NULL THEN COLLECT({id: user2.id, weight: 5}) ELSE [] END) AS data 
WITH res + data AS res 

UNWIND res AS result
RETURN result.id, SUM(result.weight) AS weight;
```

I visually broke up this query into separate blocks of Cypher, to make it easier to read.

The query keeps extending (and replacing) the `res` collection with appropriate `id`/`weight` pairs, and then aggregates at the end.

The block with 2 `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses could have been written using a single `OPTIONAL MATCH`, but I thought it was more performant do the same work piecemeal, and to allow the failure of one `OPTIONAL MATCH` to potentially inform Cypher to not even bother with the other one. The block's second `WHERE` clause relies on the `user2` node that is found by the first `OPTIONAL MATCH`. `user2` would have the value `NULL` if the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` failed, and such a `NULL` value would also cause the second `WHERE` clause to fail (which would in turn make `userRel3` `NULL`).

Comment: thanks it works. I have opened an new post more general with neo4j performance issue based on such query : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789389/mysql-vs-cypher-vs-gremlin-on-union-query